# Firefox 54 (ubuntu 14.04): Twilio video failed getUserMedia

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

2017-06-30 08:42:02.920Z | WARN in [createLocalTracks #1]: Call to getUserMedia failed: MediaStreamError { name: "InternalError", message: "Starting video failed", constraint: "", stack: "" }  twilio-video.min.js:92:26979
Unable to access local media MediaStreamError { name: "InternalError", message: "Starting video failed", constraint: "", stack: "" }

Comment: Hello! What code caused this? Are you able to use the `getUserMedia` API yourself to get access to the camera outside of Twilio Video?

Comment: @philnash Thank. I used navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia. It was an error : MediaStreamError { name: "InternalError", message: "Starting video failed", constraint: "", stack: "" }

Comment: Looks like you've got a problem between firefox and ubuntu. Does it work in Chrone?

Comment: Now it's working but Chrome does not work. I understand. It only works on one browser?

Comment: Are you trying to use it in two browsers at the same time?

Comment: Yes. I use it in two browsers

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have an issue with system resources here. One app can only get access to the camera at a time, so if it's being used by Chrome, then Firefox can't access it.

I recommend just testing in one browser, possibly using private mode so you can log in as a different user.

Make sure you handle the error case when you can't get access to the camera too.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: We are getting a similar issue - thought the issue was as you suggest but rebooting the computer and only opening Firefox reproduces the issue. This is on a Windows 10 machine with a Logitech webcam, Firefox 54.

Any ideas on what may be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: @RogerWalsh Are you able to use Chrome in this situation?

Comment: thanks for getting back @philnash! Can use Chrome, but the web app we are developing is public facing, just trying to get to the bottom of as many issues as poss for usability... Kinda got around it. Before room creation I'm now attempting a local stream. If it fails just take users to a support page. We'll just recommend Chrome as it's most stable for sure.

Thanks again!

Comment: @RogerWalsh I was only asking to make sure the camera was working! Might be worth raising an issue with the Firefox team if it really is unable to connect to your webcam. Can I just check, you're getting the error message  "Starting video failed" rather than a permissions issue?

Comment: Seems like a specific device issue. Old cam, laptop with Firefox on windows 10 is perfect. error is 

MediaStreamError { name: "InternalError", message: "Starting video failed", constraint: "", stack: "" }

Comment: Yeah, best idea is to report the device to the Firefox team and see whether they can fix it in a later version of the browser.